# Adding Functionality (Buttons/TextViews) under a tab in an Android app

Tags: java, android, android-tabs

I have an  application with three tabs. Under each, I'd like to be able to do things such as add buttons and/or `TextViews` to add functionality or show content. I have set up tabs using `TabsPagerAdapter`, and they all work fine. I have added button and `TextView` elements to the `xml` file for a tab, but when I try to connect them using `findViewById`, I get errors because the class is not an activity class.

How do I get app functionality under a tab?

Comment: You need to post your code here

Comment: In your fragment, in your onCreateView use view.findViewById instead of findViewById directly

Comment: But I still can't access the Button or TextView outside of the onCreateView method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Ahmed Hafez suggested you can use your root view in your fragment or use, from your fragment as well :

```
getActivity().findViewById().
```

Both would work. The first option is a little more precise in case 2 view share the same id (which would not be a very good pactice).

Comment: But I still can't access the Button or TextView outside of the onCreateView method.

Comment: Ahh, I see now. I needed to work with a global variable and then use the view.findViewById method you suggested. Thanks guys!

Comment: Well, you should avoid the term and concept "global variable", the context or view is passed or has to be passed to methods and classes that need it.

Comment: Sorry, I was referring to my Button variable, not my View.